# Eclipse shows login screen on start of an ABAP program

Tags: eclipse, abap, sap-erp

I have a question regarding ABAP in Eclipse.
I have the problem that if I want to start a program through Eclipse there is at the first time a SAP-Logon login screen.

Workflow is like:

1. Start Eclipse
2. Login into the SAP System
   [image: logon for project]
3. Run ABAP program (F8)
4. Login screen of SAP pop up WHY???
   [image: Login screen of SAP system]
5. I don't enter any details here only click on the OK button and it works...

I know that other people in my company don't have this issue.
May you have an idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for some reason your eclipse didn't save the credentials, maybe secure storage is corrupted. Try to re-create ABAP project

Answer (score 0):

ABAP Development Tools does not run programs, transactions, and classes by itself, in a native, Eclipse-managed view. It only opens a window as a frame for a SAP GUI connection, similar to pressing the button "Open SAP GUI (Ctrl+6)".

Opening a new SAP GUI connection always requires a new login. That's actually a feature, because you might want to switch clients and/or language.

Many features of the ABAP world are not (yet) natively available in the ABAP Development Tools. Instead of providing Eclipse-managed views for them, the environment will then resort to the nested SAP GUI display you observe here.

For example, a while back, opening a structure or table data type in the Data Dictionary would open the same kind of SAP GUI connection, start transaction SE11 inside, and display the data type there. Now there's a native view for that that will display you the data type in a textual, CDS-like format.

Comment: It's a good explanation but this doesn't answer the question. The problem is that OP's eclipse doesn't save creds, there shouldn't be any additional credential prompt after the F8